# Sending emails with attachments using windows services

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application which generates payslip for each employee as pdf and it should send these pdfs to corresponding employees email addresse,is it possible using windows services or what is the best way to to do this without consuming application performance?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use SMTPClient or EWS.